# Delete objects in backbone-relational

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, backbone-relational

let's say I have two HasMany relationships:

```
Playlist: HasMany Clips
```

and

```
ClipsMegaCollection: HasMany Clips
```

The idea is to have a sorted list of `Playlists` and keep a `ClipsMegaCollection` synchronized as the planar list of clips reflecting all the playlists.

Is this possible with backbone-relational, or can anyone think of a way of doing this in backbone?

I can have `ClipsMegaCollection.comparator` return a key depending on `Playlist` order and `Clip` order within the playlist, so keeping things sorted should be OK.

The problem is that I need to keep things synchronized when clips are added or removed from playlists, or moved around

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: edited, I was attacked by a wild ENTER keypress